# Spring Boot json schema validation with version draft 07 throws JsonSchemaException: Unknown MetaSchema: https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema

Tags: json, spring-boot, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

## Problem

Validating a json with the json schema validator throws an exception loading the json schema file:

```
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.findMetaSchemaForSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:267)
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.createValidationContext(JsonSchemaFactory.java:258)
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.newJsonSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:252)
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:296)
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:304)
    at com.example.demojsonschemavalidation07.JsonSchemaValidator.validate(JsonSchemaValidator.java:28)
    at com.example.demojsonschemavalidation07.JsonSchemaValidatorTest.test_valid_message(JsonSchemaValidatorTest.java:19)
...
```

- Json Schema Version draft-07: https://json-schema.org/learn/miscellaneous-examples.html

  - the lib contributer already tested my inputs, so the validator lib works as expected: https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator/commit/236967ad478802233ddf1f5e277bf0903af47e5a
- Json Validator: https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator
- Spring Boot Project: 2.2.10

## Test project

https://github.com/nusmanov/spring-boot-json-schema-validation/

### Json Schema

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's last name."
    },
    "age": {
      "description": "Age in years which must be equal to or greater than zero.",
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    }
  }
}
```

#### JSON Text

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 21
}
```

Full exception

---

```
com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaException: Unknown MetaSchema: https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema

    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.findMetaSchemaForSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:267)
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.createValidationContext(JsonSchemaFactory.java:258)
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.newJsonSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:252)
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:296)
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:304)
    at com.example.demojsonschemavalidation07.JsonSchemaValidator.validate(JsonSchemaValidator.java:28)
    at com.example.demojsonschemavalidation07.JsonSchemaValidatorTest.test_valid_message(JsonSchemaValidatorTest.java:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)



Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Found the Bug

`JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance()` was using the default Version 4.

### Fix

`JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(VersionFlag.V7).getSchema(schemaPath.getInputStream());`

Comment: Right, you can usually force a specific draft (dialect) to be used, but it's better to auto detect based on the dialect defined in the schema itself.

Comment: OK ! Same to me but I had to add JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V201909)...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `s` from `https` for the URI of draft-07.

The URI for draft-07 is `http://...`.

The URI used to identify a schema dialect is not necessarily network addressable... in other words, "It's just a string", which should match completely.

Comment: It looks like you should ideally use automatic detection, which is supported: https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator/blob/master/doc/specversion.md#to-create-a-jsonschemafactory-automatically-detecting-schema-version

Comment: "It looks like you should ideally use automatic detection, which is supported" 100% agree with you, thx.